# using double but not necessarily needing a decimal number

Tags: java

i need to create a code wherein if the user inputs a whole number to a double variable type, it will proceed as a whole number but if it's a decimal number, it will say "insufficient data" and terminate the program something like:

```
System.out.println("Enter Amount: ");

double am2=snsd.nextDouble;

if (am2==whole number) {

System.out.println();

if (ace1==2 && am2>=500 && am2<=dbal) {

dbal=(dbal-am2);

System.out.println("Balance: " +dbal); }

else if (ace1==2 && am2<500) {

System.out.println("INSUFFICIENT AMOUNT");

System.exit(0); }

else if (ace1==2 && am2>dbal) {

System.out.println("INSUFFICIENT BALANCE");

System.exit(0); } }

else if (am2==decimal number) {

System.out.println("INSUFFICIENT AMOUNT");

System.exit(0); }
```

Comment: `double am2=snsd.nextDouble;` is incorrect: you do not call the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
double elm=snsd.nextDouble;
if(elm%1>0)
{
sop("InSufData");
terminate();
}else{
}
```

Using elm%1 will give a number greater than 0 when its not a whole no

Answer (score 0):

You can try to convert double to string, split it using . and the part after decimal should be zero for a whole number.

Answer (score 0):

Read the number as string, then try to convert the string to an int. If the conversion is successful, then further convert the number to a double. Otherwise, print an error message.

```
double n;
try {
    String input = snsd.next();
    n = 1.0 * Integer.parseInt(input);
} catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
    System.out.println("INSUFFICIENT AMOUNT");
}
```